# Are there famous developers using Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community

We know Jeff and Joel use Stack Overflow (obviously), but what other "famous" developers or at least working on popular projects, or important blogs do you know of that are using Stack Overflow?

Define famous:
Book authors, popular project leaders/developers (think [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), an IDE, a database engine, etc., stuff we ask about here at Stack Overflow). I mean famous as in "has done something important for the rest of us".

Comment: At least you should put that Wiki... and this has been already discussed... let me find the old post.

Comment: I think this would be best as a community wiki.

Comment: Oops...9 second spread on those. :)

Comment: EBgreen edit some words in the text. We need 4 edits to make that wiki. I already edited.

Comment: Alright, now it's wiki. I can't find the previous post about that question. This might be deleted.

Comment: I definitely remember the previous question, but yeah, might be deleted

Comment: I haven't read the previous post, but it would be cool if you could find it though.

Comment: What if you're famous but not for programming?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question MusiGenesis.

Comment: Yes it does. If Charles Manson ever takes up programming, he will instantly be a "famous developer".

Comment: Now you've gone and made Angelina and the kids cry. Shame on you!

Comment: :P I guess I should have made my question more specific. But yeah, I guess if an already famous celebrity became a developer, it would be a famous developer. I meant famous as in "has done something important for the rest of us".

Comment: The answer is "yes."

Comment: Is it a reflection on them or on me if I say I haven't heard of any of these people?

Comment: @dacracot, you should at least have heard of Jon Skeet!

Comment: What i love about checking out the profiles of these people is to read the answers they give to their own specialization.

Comment: Google squillman.  Hey look, I'm famous.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: What programming language would Charles Manson choose?

Comment: Here's to 50. @Squillman, you just reminded me, I come up in the first page of Google Images for my name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/548637/vogella

Comment: do you forgot MSFT man [Raymond Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) ?????

Comment: [Adrian Holovaty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1846483/adrian-holovaty), co-creator of Django

Answer (score 135):

Stack Overflow exists because [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) allows it.

Comment: Are you in love with jon skeet or something?  that is kinda creepy

Comment: No, @theman, he is continuing a joke started on Stackoverflow earlier.

Comment: Although new readers could be forgiven for thinking that being in love with JS was a condition of membership...

Comment: Members aren't in love with Jon Skeet. Members are in love with up-voting Jon Skeet.  You get $1 every time you do.  It's auto-tracked.

Comment: If you want to move from purgatory to heaven vote for jon skeet!

Comment: jon skeet fanboyism makes me sick, even if its a joke started earlier.

Comment: i laugh at you being sick

Comment: > jon skeet fanboyism makes me sick
every religion has to start somewhere and somehow ... ;-)

Comment: is jone skeet Neil Patrick Harrison of C#?

Comment: I saw Jon Skeet's book in a local Barnes & Nobles recently. Congrats, Jon - your book is famous enough to make it across the pond and not be bought in bookstores in the American South.

Comment: @CodeToGlory - Who is Jone Skeet and who is Neil Patrick Harrison? Get your names right, dude.

Comment: What do you mean `allows it`?

Comment: He's in the top *.01%* for rep.

Comment: I thought Stack Overflow exists because Chuck Norris allows it.

Comment: @DiegoPino, you thought wrong

Comment: When he hits 1.000.000 reputation, will he throw a party?

Comment: i hate flattering

Answer (score 111):

We're all famous, aren't we? :)

Comment: I'd like to think so!

Comment: Five minutes of fame!

Comment: "My Mom says I'm cool." --Milhouse (The Simpsons)

Comment: yes we are famous :)

Comment: at least in our own minds.

Comment: @Esko : No. Only if you have a `♦`, or if you're among the top 10% of highest rep users.

Comment: @rlb: My gravatar has multiple stars, does that count?)

Comment: @Esko : No. We think of gravatar avatars as laziness.

Comment: @rlb: But I'm lazy by definition, I'm an engineer!

Comment: @Esko, well, since you're so determined to be famous, you just might be some day. Perhaps you may rank #2 on SO rep - right behind Skeet of course.

Answer (score 108):

How about [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), one of the principal developers on the C# compiler team?

Comment: Surprised this one was six answers down the page.

Comment: He is one of the developers of the compiler, but I'm sure he would be surprised to find out that he was one of the people who created the language.

Comment: He's so cool he can talk about himself in third person (on his profile) (no disrespect intended)

Answer (score 79):

[Alan Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48710/alan-kay) is in the house!

Comment: Define "in the house" ;) - he's answered one question, which was about himself ... ;)

Comment: he's asked one now which i predict might be quite popular :)

Comment: @Thomas Hansen - Mind you, so did Jon Skeet, although it's not the only question he's answered ;-}

Comment: >2000 reputation with 1 question and 1 answer.  *Wow.*

Comment: The answer about himself being: *I don't remember*. Congratulations!

Comment: Does it count as Metaprogramming?

Comment: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them. but you still sharing .. ehhh

Answer (score 74):

[John Resig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524) (Mr. jQuery)

Comment: +1. I wasn't able to find him using search :)

Comment: +1 finally,ONE postwhere I can't say 'not enough jquery'

Answer (score 61):

[Bjarne Stroustrup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109934/bjarne-stroustrup) - a computer scientist most notable for developing the C++ programming language. He joined Stack Overflow in May 2009.

Comment: He joined in may, answer one single question, got 20 up votes and never come back.

Comment: *Its now one hundred thousand votes!*

Comment: I guess that if he had engaged more in Stackoverflow he should have to answer many questions :)

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times." Yet he got it 5 times in 2 days lol.

Comment: and the only answer he provided seems more like a Link Only answer :D

Answer (score 52):

[Chief Mono Monkey and father of Gnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/migueldeicaza)

[That Microsoft guy who writes about Africa (among other things)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) -  ;)

Comment: w00t i have more rep than both of them, does that make me cool?

Comment: I'm sure they have better things to do

Comment: Which this had been two separate answers.

Comment: About Africa, amongst other things. That's hilarious.

Comment: @Olafur, I asked about this somewhere. If a God like Miguel de Icaza were answering questions on .Net and not just on Mono, he'd have a much bigger rep. Perhaps as big as yours?

Answer (score 43):

Python Guru, [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli).

I wasn't sure if it was really him at first, but given the amount of reputation he has amassed so quickly, and the fact that [Joel gave a talk at Google](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ) a couple weeks ago... seems legit :-).

Comment: His answers are great but who is Alex Martelli? One of the core developers?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Alex Martelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Martelli)

Answer (score 36):

[Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz) was a high-profile Perl god at one point and has written [quite a few books on the subject](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=randal+schwartz&x=0&y=0) (eat your heart out [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)).  I don't know to what extent he's still involved in Perl development, but he's turned up now as a [Smalltalk/Seaside consultant](http://methodsandmessages.vox.com/).

[Martin Von Lowis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33006/martin-v-l246wis) is quite a major contributor in Python Circles (at least I'd heard of him).

I think we've invented a new game - Stackoverflow Celebrity Watch.

*Ewww.*  Now I feel like a stalker :-p

Comment: Although Stonehenge, the company Randal and I run, mostly does Perl consulting, we now do Smalltalk consulting too. We haven't abandoned Perl and we just updated our Learning Perl book this summer.

Comment: +1 for Randal. Awesome guy, and what Intel did to him was an extreme injustice.

Comment: +1 - As far as I know, Randal Schwartz is the only regular SO user (besides Joel) who has written a book that I've actually read.

Comment: @Bill - you haven't read any of brian d foy's? :)

Comment: @DVK: My Perl skills are ancient and crusty, so much so that I have to stay out of the tag.  I have an early edition of *Learning Perl* from before @brain d foy was listed as an author (maybe he was a contributor but didn't get full author credit? I don't know, he'd have to answer that).  I should probably get an up-to-date copy of the book.  Maybe this is why the 5-10 `perl` answers I've left on SO have mostly been downvoted. :)

Comment: @Bill - I count a total of 5 perl tag answers for 25 total votes. Not too shabby as far as averages go :)

Answer (score 30):

For the Delphi community: [Nick Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044/nick-hodges) is quite famous.

Comment: He's great for Delphi, at least what I remember from the borland.public days ...

Comment: He's still great for Delphi

Answer (score 28):

There are only two users here (besides Jeff and Joel) that I have heard of before (=famous?). Those are [Kent Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13842/kent-beck) of Extreme Programming fame, and [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) (a lead developer on the Zend Framework library).

Comment: I hadn't even heard of Jeff and Joel until recently...

Comment: Bill Karvin: an EX lead developer at Zend Framework

Comment: :o The "Kent Beck" ??? I though someone took his name, like... CheGueVerra... Is that him really?

Comment: Are you crazy, I'm less than dust besides the great Kent Beck, but feel somehow pleased that, someone thought he might be me ... :D

Comment: I'm still hyped about Oscar's comment .. must be a slow day at work ...
Him and Fowler, are guys that I really respect there work.

Comment: @[CheGueVerra]: LOL - no one thinks you're Kent Beck or Che, Oscar was referring to Kent! But I am curious why you'd choose the notorious communist revloutionary and executioner Che Guevara as your avatar...and then misspell his name!

Comment: Easy, I'm not him or claim to be, as for the reason see here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357167/what-is-the-origin-of-your-so-username#357229

Comment: Yup, I misunderstood that completly ... lol ah well, still made my day.

Comment: @Che: Me and Fowler? ? ? :-O Well thank you Now you made my day LOL :P :P Nahh sorry man, I attempt to say : " Probably someone took Kent's name in the same fashion someone took Che's" And I understand. Kent, Folwer [and Me ;)]  Are those who you really respect.

Comment: @tharkun: Doesn't his profile still says he is?

Comment: @alex: I was the project lead on ZF through their 1.0 release.  I left Zend in October 2007, and stopped contributing to the project.

Answer (score 27):

[Walter Bright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33949/walter-bright) is the father of the [D programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)).

I think it's interesting to note that most of these *famous* developers have rather low reputations ([Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) excluded of course) it almost makes you think they have better things to do with their time...

Comment: I'm a big Fan of D, but I don't think Walter Bright is that famous, or else, D would've been more famous, i.e. more mainstream

Comment: it's time is coming...

Comment: brian d foy is a leader in Perl tag.

Comment: [Andrei Alexandrescu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348571/andrei) is also here now.

Comment: @hasen: Walter used to be famous for Zortech C++ before he invented D.

Answer (score 26):

[**Jan Goyvaerts**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33358/jan-goyvaerts) is the webmaster of [**regular-expressions.info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/about.html): a true Regex Master.

Answer (score 26):

I consider [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy) to be famous, and he's quite active here (rep 6K+ and a very frequent editor of questions and answers).  Interesting that I don't see his name mentioned with a couple of other Perl programmers who were mentioned.

Comment: Well, outside of Perl I'm a nobody :)

Comment: Coincidentally, outside of Perl I'm a brian d foy :)

Comment: Nothing that exists is truly outside of Perl! :)

Comment: @skiphoppy - You don't know how right you are. http://xkcd.com/224/

Comment: @Chris Lutz They say Emacs has a macro for that, too.

Comment: No longer this user exist...

Comment: @nicael I fixed the link.

Answer (score 24):

- [Allison Randal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118141/what-exactly-is-parrot/121996#121996)(user account deleted) - [Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/)'s Chief Architect.
- [Phil Haack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598/haacked) - MS blogger/dev
- [Scott Hanselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) - MS blogger/dev
- [Obie Fernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10142/obie) - Ruby/Rails blogger/dev

Comment: Obie posted a single question and leave. I think forever. Probably I think he would have liked SO to be written RoR

Comment: I don't see Allison Randal's page. Am I crazy, or is that link broken?

Comment: Updated the link to an Allison Randal answer. Looks like her user account is closed.

Comment: Randal's answer has since been deleted.  For those of you who don't believe it ever existed, see this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hXUie.png).

Answer (score 24):

[Allen Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20552/allen-bauer) and [Barry Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3712/barry-kelly) are also quite famous in the Delphi community.

Answer (score 21):

I am a famous programmer, just not yet.  Maybe another ten years.

Comment: yea keep dreaming "karl".. ive seen your code

Comment: so... still hopefull?..... for the next 10 years?....

Answer (score 20):

[Andreas Hausladen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44005/andreas) writes a lot of useful fixes for the Delphi IDE, we call him "The Delphi God", when he posts some new fix on his blog we just say "The Delphi God strikes again!".

Seriously now, for me and my coworkers he is the guy we admire the most, because he contributes a lot to make our work easier and less stressful (as he fixes a lot of stuff before, and some times better than even codegear).

Comment: My vote for him. Very useful stuff.

Answer (score 18):

[Larry Osterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761503/larry-osterman) , a pretty well-known MSDN blogger.

Answer (score 18):

From the Apple / Objective-C / Cocoa community, there are several well-known individuals...

- [Chris Espinosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25972/) — Apple employee #8, now lead for Xcode
- [Chris Hanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714/) — Apple employee in Developer Tools
- [Bill Bumgarner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/) (aka "bbum") — Apple employee and Objective-C runtime guru
- [Malcom Crawford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23233/) — Apple employee in techpubs (writes lots of Apple documentation)
- [Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461/) — Developer for Growl and Adium
- [Matt Gallager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36103/) — Author of the excellent [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com) blog
- [Wil Shipley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30602/wil-shipley) – co-founder of The Omni Group and founder of Delicious Monster
- [Marcus Zarra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10673/marcus-s-zarra) - Author of several excellent Cocoa books and author on the [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://cimgf.com) blog
- [Chris Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49732/chris-parker) - Apple frameworks developer

Answer (score 17):

The creator of Python: [Guido van Rossum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum)

Answer (score 13):

I read a post of [Bruce Eckel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44200/bruce-eckel) today.

Comment: The account is no more.

Answer (score 13):

[Robert Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73476/uncle-bob) - Aka Uncle Bob - from [ObjectMentor](http://blog.objectmentor.com/). However, imho, Robert Martin doesn't pay attention to SO as much as he used to after [Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood's childish sarcasm on him](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/02/06/on-open-letter-to-joel-spolsky-and-jeff-atwood). I might be wrong, though.

Comment: I doubt that. He subsequently appeared on the podcast as a guest (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/podcast-41/) and it seems like he was on relatively good terms with Atwood and Spolsky.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think Uncle Bob occasionally appears where there is mention of one of the SOLID principles. I [answered this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621800/business-logic-in-constructors-a-good-idea/621860#621860) a while back linking to his paper on SOLID, and Uncle Bob popped up later that day and [answered the question himself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621800/business-logic-in-constructors-a-good-idea/622120#622120) (much better than I managed to, as well.)

Answer (score 13):

I ([Marco Cantù](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45145/marco-cantu)) am the author of over a dozen books on Delphi, published around the world. Do I count as a famous developer? Probably only in the given community, "Delphi"...

Comment: I don't know you, but if that's true, then yes you're geek famous.

Answer (score 12):

["I don't know how to put this but I'm kind of a big deal."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Burgundy)

Answer (score 12):

[D. Richard Hipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24830/richard-hipp) the maker of SQLite and Fossil to name a few of his open source and public domain projects

One of the un-sung heroes in my books

Comment: page not found?

Comment: The page seems to have disappeared. His name is D. Richard Hipp, not Dr. He may also be a doctor but the D. is an initial.

Answer (score 11):

[Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) joined Stack Overflow in March 2010.

> Herb Sutter is a prominent C++ expert.
>   He is also a book author and a
>   columnist for Dr. Dobb's Journal. He
>   joined Microsoft in 2002 as a platform
>   evangelist for Visual C++ .NET, rising
>   to lead software architect for
>   C++/CLI. Sutter served as secretary
>   and convener of the ISO C++ standards
>   committee for over 10 years. ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Sutter))

Answer (score 10):

[Andrei Alexandrescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348571/andrei), an author of several C++ programming books and one of the creators of the D programming language.

Comment: That's not actually *the* Andrei Alexandrescu, as far as I can tell. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348571/andrei) is his real account.

Comment: @Michael: Oh, okay. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 10):

The creator of Scala: [Martin Odersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210303/martin-odersky)

Answer (score 9):

I saw [Kent Beck](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/) on here a while ago

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/are-there-famous-developers-using-stack-overflow/16142#16142

Answer (score 7):

I'd heard of [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50648/romain-guy) (co-author of the Java book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/)) before he showed up here. He seems to have posted one answer and left, though.

Answer (score 6):

[Ayende Rahien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366/ayende-rahien)

Prolific developer/blogger well known in the .NET community. (also creator of [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx))

Comment: He seems quite inactive.

Answer (score 6):

[Kevin Bourrillion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202214/kevin-bourrillion), of [Google Collections fame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM#t=2m54s) (nowerdays [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)), is a pretty active user.

Ok, not as famous in the Java world as, say, [Josh Bloch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564385/josh-bloch) (who is an infrequent user), but quite well-known as he leads what definitely is a popular project.

Answer (score 5):

[Jesse Liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11090/jesse-liberty), author of [several](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=jesse+liberty&x=0&y=0) programming books and Silverlight blogger.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet, for his book C# in Depth. He is a very active SO user.

Comment: It was a joke and bad answer at the time, but in the year since I think it's worth taking seriously.

Answer (score 4):

I see [Frans Bouma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44991/frans-bouma) recently registered.

Comment: And he was kind enough to answer a question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430774/how-to-minimize-customer-service-help-desk-time-for-programmers#430792

Answer (score 4):

I've written books about programming, but I'm not famous. 99% of the people mentioned in the answers here aren't famous either. John Resig, Miguel de Icaza, and Ray Ozzie qualify as famous. The other dudes, meh.

Just another navel-gazing poll on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not famous.

However, I'm in Wikipedia in a few places due to my programming. But that shows how big Wikipedia is, not how big I am.

Answer (score 4):

[Rudy Velthuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) of [TeamB](http://www.teamb.com/) fame is on [SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com) too.
Besides being very knowledgeable, he is also a really nice person.

--jeroen

Answer (score 4):

[Reto Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822/reto-meier), author of a couple of well known books on Android.

Answer (score 4):

Terence Parr: https://stackoverflow.com/users/275496/terence-parr

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Parr):

> Terence John Parr (b. Los Angeles, August 17, 1964) is a professor of computer science at the University of San Francisco. He is best known for his ANTLR parser generator and contributions to parsing theory. He also developed the StringTemplate engine for Java and other programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

[Jason Garrett-Glaser (aka Dark Shikari)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11206/dark-shikari), author of x264

Answer (score 2):

Didn't Jeff mention on [the podcast](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4) that [Ray Ozzie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Ozzie) uses Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2):

If you're a game developer, the name [Andrew Rollings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40410/andrew-rollings) might be familiar/famous, from his books

[Game Architecture and Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735713634) (used as a textbook in many college game-development curricula) and

[Andrew Rollings and Ernest Adams on Game Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592730019).

See also [hiivebooks.com](http://www.hiivebooks.com)

Comment: Dammit steven, I was trying to remain anonymous! :)

Comment: @[Andrew Rollings]: uh...you'd have to be quiet for that to happen, and we both know you just...can't...do...that!

Answer (score 2):

[Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), [Java Champion](https://java-champions.dev.java.net/content/corechampions.html#Colebourne) and creator of the [clichéd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835418/what-are-the-stackoverflow-standard-answers/835423#835423) [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library, appears occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

[Karl E Peterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121018/karl-e-peterson) has recently joined, and has been well-known in the Classic VB community for many years for his [many contributions](http://vb.mvps.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[Ryan Bates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148722/ryanb) is here. I don't about any other community, but in Ruby on Rails community he is one the biggest names. Almost every new Ruby on Rails programmer learns through his excellent Railscasts!

Answer (score 2):

[Stefan Küng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48003/stefan) - the lead developer of TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

[Eelco Hillenius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445367/eelco) and [Igor Vaynberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410414/igor-vaynberg) are about as famous as it gets in the [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org) community.

EDIT:
[Martijn Dashorst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611274/martijn-dashorst) is now here too!

Answer (score 2):

*This just in*:
[Chris Okasaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796917/chris-okasaki), author of "Purely Functional Data Structures"

Answer (score 1):

> "has done something important for the
>   rest of us"

[I don't know how many *was-Palm-programmmer*s are around here.]

The other day I was glad to see [Ben Combee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323/ben-combee) here, and also [Tim Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2716/tim-norman).
Ben Combee gave back a lot to the Palm community.
Tim gave an [excellent product](http://www.pocket-tunes.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

[**Alf P. Steinbach**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/alf-p-steinbach) : One of the [moderators](http://www.gotw.ca/resources/clcm.htm#Policy) of the usenet group [comp.lang.c++.moderated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/topics)

Answer (score 1):

[Ramnivas Laddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485671/ramnivas), Spring Framework Committer and Author of [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Larry O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10116/larry-obrien) was the editor of three very good and now defunct magazines: "Software Development", "Computer Language", and "AI Expert".

Answer (score 1):

[Ceki Gülcü](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100970/ceki), founder of log4j, slf4j, Logback projects. Very much active on SO.

Answer (score 1):

- [Bob Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300162/bob-lee) : [Android](http://www.android.com/) lead, [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) creater, co-Spec Lead of [JSR 330](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)
- [Neal Gafter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241658/neal-gafter) : [Resume](http://www.gafter.com/~neal/resume.html)
- [Cedric Beust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162410/cedric-beust) : Creator of the Java testing framework [TestNG](http://testng.org/)
- [Ben Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245018/ben-alex) : Principal Software Engineer with [SpringSource](http://www.springsource.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[jay bazuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5314/jay-bazuzi) is famous cause he blogs about pizza

[Exhibit A](http://jbazuzi.blogspot.com/2008/08/pizza.html)

Comment: lol this guy is great

Answer (score 0):

[Jeni Tennison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6739/jenit) and [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) (XML/XSLT)

Comment: I think also Dr. Michael Kay was here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not entirely famous yet but [Brian McNamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19299/brian) from the F# development team has a signficant 16K+ rep at the time of adding him to the list.

Answer (score 0):

[Steve Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75123/steve-freeman), one of the authors of [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321503627)

Answer (score 0):

[Stan Kelly-Bootle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172563/any-computer-language-magazine-archive-around/4335045#4335045) was here too!

For those poor souls who don't know him: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Kelly-Bootle

Answer (score -1):

Jim Anderson is also on here, which is pretty cool.

Answer (score -2):

I'm an infamous programmer.

Comment: dumb answer if i could down vote you i would

Comment: @theman: there is no dumb answer. There are only dumb questions. ;-)

Comment: "... Remember, there are no stupid questions, just stupid people." -- Mr. Garrison, South Park

Comment: You are so famous, you are infamous.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure I've ever really heard of any 'famous' developers, maybe famous among developers but that doesn't really equate to fame in my mind. Edward Norton is a famous actor, but not just among actors. There are few developers that I would consider famous as nobody outside the developer community has any clue, most people not even having a clue what a developer even is.

Comment: ryan, you are right

Comment: I bet more people know who Bill Gates is then Edward Norton.

Comment: Who's Edward Norton? (No, really, I've never heard the name before.)

Comment: Who is Linux named after? Maybe that guy is famous.

Comment: Didn't he do the Norton Utilities? :-)

Comment: I would call Carmack famous. Just. Above a Big Brother escapee but below the person who does that advert. With the elephant. Yeah you know the one I mean.

Answer (score -3):

Just stumbled upon an answer by [Cory Foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4083/cory-foy).

Comment: Is he famous? In what context?