# Who are famous users of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, community

For example I know

- [Jason Garrett-Glaser (aka Dark Shikari)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11206/dark-shikari) - author of x264
- [Terence Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao) - Fields Medal holder

There is a similar question about developers-only, *[Are there famous developers using Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/are-there-famous-developers-using-stack-overflow)*.

Comment: Voted to close as this is entirely opinion based. I have never heard of those 2 that the OP mentions, and while @ShadowWizard lists the most famous one I know, most of the famous folks I would list would be unknown to people outside my discipline.

Answer (score 4):

[Peter Shor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Shor) is a mathematician and a professor at MIT. He is best known for his [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), which allows a [quantum computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) to efficiently find prime factors of large numbers. This might not sound like a big deal, but once we are actually able to create quantum computers of a decent size, we have to replace (almost) all encryption schemes which are currently in use.

As a mathematician, of course he's active at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2294/peter-shor) and [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1677/peter-shor), but it is interesting to see that he's one of the top users at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5754/peter-shor), which I assume is more like a hobby to him.

I recently learned the [1999 Physics Nobel Prize winner, Gerard 't Hooft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_%27t_Hooft#Honors) has also been active on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft).

Answer (score 2):

No doubt the most famous person that ever had an active account on a Stack Exchange site is [frosty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249338/frosty) aka Ross Ulbricht.

I don't think there is a need to explain why he's so famous, world wide.

The relation to Stack Overflow is explained well [here](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/10/02/silk_road_s_dread_pirate_ross_ulbricht_asked_stack_overflow_question_under.html), and it's also discussed here in [Did the Stack Exchange staff members assist in the apprehension of Ross Ulbricht?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht).

Comment: I immediately recognized Peter Shor's name in comments, but had to look up Ross Ulbricht. Not sure what that says about me.

Comment: @NathanTuggy same here (well, I immediately recognized his name on EL&U)