# Stack Overflow login is very complicated without third-party cookies and NoScript

Tags: support, login, openid, javascript, cookies

I try to login with OpenID (stackexchange.com provider) with third-party cookies disabled and [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) (with sane setup: always allow main domain).

First you need to click two times "temporary allow all" to be able to click on the Stack Overflow login-button. Then you shortly see the login page, then you get redirected to a page "you do not allow third-party cookies, click here". After clicking, there finally is a working login form.

This is a lot more hassle, than you would expect from a professional site.

JavaScript is okay, but it does not need to be loaded from different third-party sites.

Login without third-party cookies should work. If this needs an intermediate step because of OpenID, there should just be a button "take me to the no-third-party-cookies login" instead of showing the login page and then redirecting to a page with only a link, which eventually points to the real login page.

Comment: Are you worried about the FBI tracking your Stack Overflow useage? That wouldn't happ- [oh wait](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht)...

Comment: Not really ;). I am just disappointed, that SO needs that many exceptions. Most sites which need that many whitelist entries, are crappy in other ways, too. But StackOverflow is well designed and easy to use ... except for these problems at login. Often a login which uses a bit of JS needs one click "temp whitelist all" or whitelisting one JS source, thats okay. I am just wondering, why is SO worse than many ugly programmed websites?

Comment: IIRC, you need to enter the openid URL manually if you don't have JS enabled.